# How can I get list of all issues related to a particular version for a repository from github api

Tags: github, github-api

For public repositories that have multiple versions of product released on github is there a way to get list of issues that are logged against particular version for the repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub's issue tracker doesn't link issues to releases or anything else that might be considered a "version".

If you manually create [milestones and / or labels](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/#filtering), and ensure that your team actively uses these features, you can then [query on them](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository), e.g.

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues?milestone=3&labels=bug,ui
```

Comment: Thanks for the information Chris. Just curious to know, does any of other Source Code repositories support this kind of mechanism?

Comment: @theja_swarup, I'm sure that some do. Even Bugzilla used to have an option to report bugs against a particular version. GitHub's issue tracker is useful (and enough for many projects), but not full-featured.

Comment: Which program did you use to run that GET command? It's not a URL and doesn't work in my browser. When I run it in a linux terminal, it starts some new process, but doesn't list anything.

Comment: @TimothySwan it's an HTTP GET request. Should work in your browser or using `curl` / `wget` / `httpie` etc. The syntax will vary. Make sure to prefix it with the base API URL (I'm on mobile and can't find it right now) and replace the `:placeholders` with real values.